# Unable to run Cucumber Tests using Tags through Maven

Tags: maven, testing, tags, cucumber, continuous-testing

when i run cucumber tests using "Run as Junit Tests", the tests runs properly with proper tags.

also when i run cucumber tests using "**Maven", the tests runs properly** with proper tags,provided i have mentioned the tags in runner class.

`@Cucumber.Options(format={"pretty", html:target/cucumber","json:target/cucumber.json"},tags= {"@smokeTest"})`

But i want to be able to provide tags as argument to mvn test command,to run the test cases and i am making use of following command.

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tagTest"
```

But it runs all the test cases irrespective of my tags.

also when i use the command **`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tagTest"`**
i mention no tags in my runner class

```
@Cucumber.Options(format={"pretty",html:target/cucumber","json:target/cucumber.json"})
```

Please let me know where am i going wrong anywhere?

This is runnerTest code:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@Cucumber.Options(format={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber","json:target/cucumber.json"})

public class runnerTest {

}
```

Attached

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoYZo.png)

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but when options are given to the maven command it overwrites all the options mentioned in the runner class.

Comment: @Grasshopper yes true, so i expected that when i am using the command 
test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smokeTest", it should be able to run and trigger only the one test cases with tags smokeTest

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that the maven command is not compatible with the version of cucumber. The argument "cucumber.options" was introduced in version 1.1.1 (please see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cukes/1DSrCLkhXZo)) but the POM shows an older version. The correct maven command for that feature on that specific cucumber version should be:

```
mvn test -Dtags=@tagTest
```

But the second issue is that there seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/387) with that feature which was not fixed at all until version 1.1.1, which is when the new argument was also introduced.

So the solution seems to be to upgrade to version 1.1.1+ of cucumber.

Comment: Thanks @Andre Barbosa that helps.